# How do you say in SQL/ActiveRecord, "Find all records where attribute is nil or 'x'"?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to find records in ActiveRecord that have an attribute that is either `nil` or some value:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class CreateModels < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def self.up
    create_table :models do |t|
      t.string   :some_property
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :models
  end
end

Model.all(:conditions => ["some_property IN (?)"], [nil, "this value"])
```

How do I set that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Model.all(:conditions => 
  ["some_property = ? or some_property is null", "this value"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split out the NULL condition separately:

```
Model.all(:conditions => [ "some_property=? OR some_property IS NULL", "this value" ])
```

To test if a value is NULL, you need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.